# Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum(s) and minimum(s)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum(s) and minimum(s) of

$$f(x,y)=2x^2+3y^2−4x−5 \text{ subject to } x^2+y^2=16$$

So far I've taken the partials of f and g:

\begin{align}
f_x &= 4x-4 \\
f_y &= 6y \\
g_x &= 2x \\
g_y &= 2y
\end{align}

Then I set them equal to each other and multiplied by $\lambda$:
\begin{align}
4x-4 &= 2x\lambda \\
6y &= 2y\lambda
\end{align}

I'm kind of stuck here where I need to solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: just use partial derivatives

Comment: If $6y = 2y\lambda$, what's $\lambda$?

Comment: 3, so would that mean x = -2? Also, if that is correct, do you know how I could solve for y? thanks

Comment: Don't forget that you have three constraints to find your three variables $x$, $y$, and $\lambda$: the two equations you got from equating partial derivatives, and the original constraint $x^2+y^2=16$.

Comment: In Lagrange multiplier problems it is vital to find **all** solutions of your equations.  So $6y=2y\lambda$ does not tell you that $\lambda=3$, it tells you that *either* $\lambda=3$ *or* $y=0$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So could I plug y back into x^2 + y^2 to find that x = +-4

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when $y=0$.  But of course $\lambda=3$ is still an option and you need to follow that through too.

Comment: So when I use lambda = 3. I also find that x = -2 so would I be looking at the points (4, 0) (-4, 0) and (-2, 0)?

Comment: Oh ok, so then would I just plug (4, 0) and (-4, 0) back into f(x,y) to find the max and min?

Comment: @Mathster Why doesn't $\lambda = 3$ work? $\lambda = 3$, $x = -2$, $y = \pm \sqrt{12}$ looks OK to me.

Comment: @user106342 Yes, once you've found all the critical points, you need to plug them back into $f$ to see what their actual values are; no shortcuts there.

Comment: Alright great, thank you so much! So now I have (-2, sqrt(12)), (-2, -sqrt(12)), (4, 0), and (-4, 0). I'll plug them back in and see what I get

Comment: @dfan Because of the exponents, my mins seem to be coming out bigger then my maxes. I'm getting Maxes: 47, 11 and Mins: 47, 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve for $y^2: y^2 = 16 - x^2 \to f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 3(16 - x^2) - 4x - 5 = -x^2 - 4x + 43 = -(x + 2)^2 + 47 = g(x)$

Consider $f(x,y) = g(x) = 47 - (x + 2)^2$ on $[-4, 4]$. Clearly:$ g(x) \leq 47$ and that $\max g(x) = 47$ when $ x = -2$ so $y^2 = 16 - (-2)^2 = 12 $, and $y = \sqrt{12}$ and$ y = - \sqrt{12}$. Observe that $g$ is minimized when $(x + 2)^2$ is maximized, and this occurs when $x = 4$. So $\min g = 47 - (4 + 2)^ = 47 - 36 = 11$.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, the constraint curve $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ 16 \ $ has four-fold symmetry about the origin, but the function $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ 2x^2 \ + \ 3y^2 \ − \ 4x \ − \ 5 \ $ is only symmetrical about the $ x- $ axis.  This indicates that we can expect critical points on the constraint circle to appear in pairs $ \ (x,y) \ $ and $ \ ( x, -y) \ $ .

For your Lagrange equations, the one involving $ \ x \ $ does not have a convenient factorization after being rearranged, but the one with $ \ y \ $ does:

$$ 4x \ - \ 4 \ = \ \lambda·2x \ \ \rightarrow \ \ (2 \ - \ \lambda)·x \ = \ 2 \ \ \ , \ \ \ 6y \ = \ \lambda·2y \ \ \rightarrow \ \ (3 \ - \ \lambda)·y \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

As discussed already in the comments above, we have either

$ \mathbf{y = 0 :  } \quad x^2 \  = \  16  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \  = \  \pm 4 \ \ , $  giving us the two function values

$ \ f(4,0) \ = \ 2·4^2 \ − \ 4·4 \ − \ 5 \ \ = \ \ 11 \ \ \ \text{or} \  \ \  f(-4,0) \ = \ 2·(-4)^2 \ − \ 4·(-4) \ − \ 5 \ \ = \ \ 43 \ \ ; $

or, applying your Lagrange equation for $ \ x \ $ ,

$ \mathbf{\lambda = 3 : }  \quad (2 \ - \ 3)·x \ = \ 2  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \  = \  -2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (-2)^2 \ + \ y^2 \  =  \ 16 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y^2 \ = \ 12 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ \pm 2\sqrt{3}  $
$$ f(-2 \ , \ \pm 2\sqrt{3}) \ = \ 2·(-2)^2 \ + \ 3·12 \  − \ 4·(-2) \ − \ 5 \ \ = \ \ 47 \ \ , $$

this latter result illustrating the function symmetry mentioned above.

The main aim here in summarizing the earlier work is to show the geometric interpretation of the problem, which also allows two of the results to be found with relatively little  calculation.  If we consider level curves of our function $ \ 2x^2 \ + \ 3y^2 \ − \ 4x \ − \ 5 \ \ = \ \ c \ \ ,  $ we can re-write this equation as

$$ 2x^2  \ − \ 4x \ + \ 3y^2  \ \ = \ \ 5 \ + \ c \ \ \rightarrow \ \ 2·(x^2  \ − \ 2x \ + \ 1 ) \ + \ 3y^2  \ \ = \ \ 5 \ + \ 2 \ + \ c  $$
$$  \rightarrow \ \ \frac{(x \ − \  1 )^2}{\left( \frac{7+c}{2} \right)} \ + \ \frac{y^2}{\left( \frac{7+c}{3} \right)}  \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ . $$

These level curves are ellipses centered on $  \ (1,0) \ $ with their major axes on the $ \ x-$ axis; the graph below shows the ellipse for $ \ c \ = \ 0 \ $ and the constraint circle.
[image]

Critical values of $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ c \ $ occur when the endpoints of the major axis are tangent to the circle, that is, when either the right endpoint lies at $  \ (4,0) \ $ or the left endpoint becomes $ \ (-4,0) \ $ .  In the first case, the distance from the center of the ellipse to the right-hand intersection of the circle with the $ \ x-$ axis is $ \ 3 \ $ , so the semi-major axis of the ellipse must be $ \ \sqrt{\frac{7+c}{2}} \ = \ 3 \ \Rightarrow \ 7 + c \ = \ 2·9 \ \Rightarrow \ c \ = \ 11 \ . $  The left $ \ x-$ intercept of the circle is $ \ 5 \ $ units from the ellipse's center, so we obtain $ \ \sqrt{\frac{7+c}{2}} \ = \ 5 \ \Rightarrow \ 7 + c \ = \ 2·25 $
$ \Rightarrow \ c \ = \ 43 \ . $  The corresponding graphs are displayed below.

[image]

This does not seem quite complete, however, as it appears that if the ellipse were made slightly larger than the $ \ c \ = \ 43 \ $ level curve, we would have the circle circumscribed by the ellipse.

**EDIT:**  We can locate the remaining tangent points by inserting the constraint condition into the level curve equation:

$$  2x^2 \ + \ 3·(16-x^2) \ - \ 4x \ - \ 5 \ \ = \ \ c \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -x^2 \ - \ 4x \ \ = \ \ c \ - \ 43 \ \ $$
$$  \Rightarrow \ \ (x \ + \ 2)^2 \ \ = \ \  47 \ - \ c \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ \ = \ \ -2 \ \pm \ \sqrt{47-c} \ \ . $$

What would be four intersection points of the level curve and constrain circle "coalesce" into two tangent points for $ \ c \ = \ 47 \ . $  We thus have the result $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ $ for the tangent points that we obtained from the $ \ \lambda \ = \ 3 \ $ case.

[image]